# Decrypt showing error authentication failed

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am using codeigniter 4.
Why is my code showing error when I'm trying to encrypt my URL ID in view?

view:

```
<?php $
  encrypter = \Config\Services::encrypter(); 
  $data1 = $value['id_aktivitas'];                         
  $data1 =  $encrypter->encrypt($data1);
?>  

<a href="<?= base_url('aktivitas/edit_aktivitas/'.$data1) ?>" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
```

and here is my controller :

```
 public function edit_aktivitas($id)
 {
    $encrypter = \Config\Services::encrypter();     
    $id = $encrypter->decrypt($id);
    $data=['aktivitas'  => $this->AktivitasModel->edit_aktivitas($id)];
 }
```

and here is my model :

```
    public function edit_aktivitas($id)
    {      
        return $this->db->table('t_aktivitas')->where('id_aktivitas', $id)->get()->getRowArray();
    }
```

I got this error

> "CodeIgniter\Encryption\Exceptions\EncryptionException Decrypting:
> authentication failed. "

Answer (score 4):

Well i ran into the same bug bro and i tried to fix it so this is my solution that worked very well for me.

1. Create a new key after setting your starter key @ App\Config\Encryption.php
2. Create an encoded key:
   Setting Your Encryption Key
   Your encryption key must be as long as the encryption algorithm in use allows. For AES-256, that’s 256 bits or 32 bytes (characters) long.

The key should be as random as possible, and it must not be a regular text string, nor the output of a hashing function, etc. To create a proper key, you can use the Encryption library’s createKey() method.

// $key will be assigned a 32-byte (256-bit) random key

```
$key = Encryption::createKey(32);
```

The key can be stored in app/Config/Encryption.php, or you can design a storage mechanism of your own and pass the key dynamically when encrypting/decrypting.

To save your key to your app/Config/Encryption.php, open the file and set:

```
public $key = 'YOUR KEY';
```

Note: passing the generated key here by copy and past will damage the binary representation so continue reading blow

**Encoding Keys or Results**

You’ll notice that the createKey() method outputs binary data, which is hard to deal with (i.e. a copy-paste may damage it), so you may use bin2hex(), hex2bin() or Base64-encoding
to work with the key in a more friendly manner. For example:

```
// Get a hex-encoded representation of the key:
  $encoded = bin2hex(Encryption::createKey(32));
  echo $encoded
```

> If you use base64_encode() make sure to use the base64_decode() in the constructor below and in encrypting your messages

e.g:

```
// if you use base64_encode do this
 $message = 'some message to encode';
 $encrypter = \Config\Services::encrypter();
 $encodedMsg = base64_encode($encrypter->encrypt($message));

 // decrypt the message 
 $txt = $encrypter->decrypt(base64_decode($encodedMsg))
 echo $txt;

// and in your App\Config\Encryption.php Constructor that will 
// dynamically decode the key to binary safe use 
base64_decode($encodedKey) 
// only if you encode the key using the 
base64_encode($key)

//And if you use 
bin2hex($key) 
// during key creation in the constructor use:
hex2bin($encodedKey) 
// and when transporting your message over url use: 
bin2hex($encodedMessageFromEncrypter->encrypt($msg)) 
// and decode it using 
hex2bin($transportedMessage)
```

#Passing the key dynamically
in your App\Config\Encryption.php

// create a constructor that will dynamically Put the same value in your config with hex2bin(),

// so that it is still passed as binary to the library:
like this:

```
public function __construct(){
   //copy the encoded key and pass it in here
   $this->key = hex2bin($encoded);
}
```

Then try to encrypt and decrypt the text again!

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue too. As mentioned in the above answer by [OBI PASCAL BANJUARE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10219856/obi-pascal-banjuare) creating **Encryption Key** is important but also note that `$data1 =  $encrypter->encrypt($data1);` generates binary data.
Do not save binary data in database, instead encode your generated binary data by using `bin2hex()` or `base64_encode()` (haven't tried base64 yet) and then save it. eg:

**ENCRYPTION**

```
encrypter = \Config\Services::encrypter(); 
$data = 'SOME_TEXT';                         
$encrypted_data =  bin2hex($encrypter->encrypt($data));
```

**DECRYPTION**

```
$decrypted_data = $encrypter->decrypt(hex2bin($encrypted_data));
echo $decrypted_data;
```

Answer (score 1):

OBI PASCAL BANJUARE has explained the answer well. To explain it in a more simple way I like to share my answer. Hopefully, it will help others in the future.

1. In Config>Encryption.php File

   `public $key = '1234567890111213';`
   // You Secret Key Length 16 words if block size 16 It can be any string
   public $blockSize = 16;
2. User it either in controller or view where you are trying to access it either to encrypt or to decrypt

   `$encrypter = \Config\Services::encrypter();`
3. Encode your value

> ```
> $co = bin2hex($encrypter->encrypt($co_id));
> $emp = bin2hex($encrypter->encrypt($emp_id));
> ```

4. Decode your value

> ```
> $co = $this->encrypter->decrypt(hex2bin($co_id));
> $emp = $this->encrypter->decrypt(hex2bin($emp_id));
> ```

**Note**: For encrypt `bin2hex` is used where as for decrypt `hex2bin` is used.

Answer (score 0):

It seems different approaches to solve this message.

May the explained and at the moment favored.

The DB-lenghts, which is also described as solution on GitHub (so thumbs up ihsan).

And in my case, I got on this page because of the same error, but my solution was the wrong steps for decode

```
bin2hex(encode($data));
```

vs.

```
hex2bin(decode($data));
```

but right is

```
decode(hex2bin($data));
```

**So it seems, it's mostly a problem with the incoming string which we would decode.**

Answer (score 0):

****codeigniter 4****

I tried to get a token from a request and I got the same error `Decrypt showing error authentication failed`

```
$token=$this->request->getVar('token');
$this->encrypt->decrypt($token);
```

The solution is

1- before sending a request, use base64_encode

```
$token =$this->encrypt->encrypt("-----");
return $this->respond(array("data"=>array("token"=>base64_encode($token))));
```

2- after receiving a request, use base64_decode

```
$token=$this->request->getVar('token');
$this->encrypt->decrypt(base64_decode($token));
```

This is working on my codeigniter project, hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

increase password field length in database. May be it solve your error

Comment: the answer is completely out of scope, in the post there is no database reference, php does not bound variable to a size nor a type.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30695039)